# Flutter filter arrays which come between 2 days

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 data lists. From first list I can find my 2 dates and time.

First data list look like this

```
"data1": [
        {

            "tripType": "active",
            "dateStart": "2021-05-31T03:02:38.000Z",
            "dateEnd": "2021-05-31T03:51:33.000Z",
            "start": {
                "lon": 66.975478,
                "lat": 24.949758,
            },
            "end": {
                "lon": 67.036706,
                "lat": 24.827635,
            }
         }];
```

On second list I have multiple arrays in which there are date and time. I want to filter this list and show only those arrays which date and time comes between on my first data starting and end time.

My second list look like this

```
"data2": [
    {
        "id": "3cec02d7-4938-418a-bcdd-c6043154a966",
        "eventDate": "2021-06-01T15:54:01.000Z",
        "creationDate": "2021-06-01T15:54:06.000Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2021-06-01T15:54:06.000Z",
        "eventClass": "overspeedevent",
        "eventType": "start",

    },
    {
        "id": "3cec02d7-4938-418a-bcdd-c6043154a966",
        "eventDate": "2021-07-01T13:54:01.000Z",
        "creationDate": "2021-06-01T13:54:06.000Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2021-06-01T13:54:06.000Z",
        "eventClass": "overspeedevent",
        "eventType": "end",

    },
    {
        "id": "3cec02d7-4938-418a-bcdd-c6043154a966",
        "eventDate": "2021-06-01T15:54:01.000Z",
        "creationDate": "2021-06-01T15:54:06.000Z",
        "modifiedDate": "2021-06-01T15:54:06.000Z",
        "eventClass": "overspeedevent",
        "eventType": "start",

    }];
```

You can see in data1 I have `dateStart` and `dateEnd` What i need is i need to find data2 between these dates in data2 i have `eventDate` I need to show or filter this array and show only those array which `eventDate` comes between `dateStart` and `dateEnd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can iterate over data2 and check the date with the compareTo method of date after converting it to date

```dart
 var startDate = DateTime.parse(data1[0]["dateStart"].toString());
 var endDate = DateTime.parse(data1[0]["dateEnd"].toString());
 for(var item in data2){
   var itemDate = DateTime.parse(item["eventDate"].toString());

   if(itemDate.compareTo(startDate) > 0 && itemDate.compareTo(endDate) < 0) {
     print(item["id"]);
   }
 }
```